# how to use findIndex with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript

I have a simple check function such as this:

```
const doesMatch = (elm, toCheck) => return elm.id === toCheck.id;
```

and I was to use it against an array with `findIndex` such as when I have the second parameter ahead of time:

```
const toCheck = {id:5}; // some obj
if (toCheck) {
  const result = largeArray.findIndex(doesMatch);
}
```

I'm unaware of how to pass the `toCheck` as a parameter into `doesMatch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ES6 function syntax to pass it to `findIndex`

```js
const toCheck = {id:5}; // some obj
if (toCheck) {
  const result = largeArray.findIndex((elm) => doesMatch(elm, toCheck));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a closure.

```js
const doesMatch = (toCheck) => {
    return (elem) => {
        return elem.id === toCheck.id;
    }
}

const toCheck = {id:5}; // some obj
if (toCheck) {
  const result = largeArray.findIndex(doesMatch(toCheck));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the parameters as part of the arrow function syntax:

```
const result = largeArray.findIndex(el => doesMatch(el, toCheck));
```

Your current initialization of *doesMatch* will through the following error:

> Missing initializer in const declaration

Should be like

```
const doesMatch = (elm, toCheck) => elm.id === toCheck.id;
```

**Demo:**

```js
const largeArray = [{id:10}, {id:15}, {id:5}, {id:25}];
const doesMatch = (elm, toCheck) => elm.id === toCheck.id;
const toCheck = {id:5}; // some obj
if (toCheck) {
  const result = largeArray.findIndex(el => doesMatch(el, toCheck));
  console.log(result); //2
}
```